# creating a simple AES encryption and decryption

Tags: java, android, security, aes

I'm attempting to create a simple encryption and decryption class. Both methods are giving the same string. I am little confused. Please need help.

Here's my code snippet:

```
public class UltimateEncryptor {

  private static final String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
  private static final String RANDOM_GENERATOR_ALGORITHM = "AES";


  // Encrypts string and encodes in Base64
  public String encrypt( String password, String data ) throws Exception 
  {
    byte[] secretKey = password.getBytes();
    byte[] clear = data.getBytes();

    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec( secretKey, CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
    cipher.init( Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec );

    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal( clear );
    String encryptedString = Base64.encodeToString( encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT );

    return encryptedString;
  }

  // Decrypts string encoded in Base64
  public String decrypt( String password, String encryptedData ) throws Exception 
  {
    byte[] secretKey = password.getBytes();
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec( secretKey, CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance( CIPHER_ALGORITHM );
    cipher.init( Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec );

    byte[] encrypted = Base64.decode( encryptedData, Base64.DEFAULT );
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal( encrypted );

    return new String( decrypted );
  }
}
```

Comment: whaat i am doing here is encrypting/ decrypting a string date occording to a given password.

Comment: `both methods i created are giving the same string. ` what do you mean by that

Comment: I mean both methods i.e. encrypt and decrypt receive two strings one is a key string and the other one is some string data.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several errors, but it's not far from working. Here are the problems:

1. You should pass `RANDOM_GENERATOR_ALGORITHM` to your `SecretKeySpec` constructor, not `CIPHER_ALGORITHM`.
2. You need to specify an IV for your encryption and decryption. Without specifying an IV, the decryption won't work because the encryption will use a random IV and your decrypt method won't know what the value is.

   ```
   cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, 
       new IvParameterSpec(/* 16 byte value */));

   cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, 
       new IvParameterSpec(/* same 16 byte value */));
   ```

   Note that you'll have to store the IV with the ciphertext, so it can be used for decryption. A common way to do this is to prefix your ciphertext value with the IV (note: the IV isn't a sensitive value). You should be using a random IV value each time you encrypt.

Some other comments:

1. Your methods should be `static` as they don't use any instance fields.
2. You should not be using the raw bytes of a password as a key. Instead, you should derive a key from a password using something [like PBKDF2](https://gist.github.com/volker48/2853610).

If you want to see some code that does this properly, see [JNCryptor](http://code.google.com/p/jncryptor/). This is an Android-compatible Java library that does password-based encryption and decryption. In particular, check out the source to see:

- [Example of key derivation from password](http://code.google.com/p/jncryptor/source/browse/trunk/jncryptor/src/main/java/org/cryptonode/jncryptor/AES256v2Cryptor.java#100)
- [Example of encryption with known IV](http://code.google.com/p/jncryptor/source/browse/trunk/jncryptor/src/main/java/org/cryptonode/jncryptor/AES256v2Cryptor.java#195)